# VirtualBox - flash player performance on a linux guest (Windows host)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, flash-player

I have the following issue.

I have windows 7 installed on my laptop and I am running
virtualbox with a ubuntu virtual machine. 
The problem is that when I try to run flash .e.g. youtube
the performance of the video is cra*.
Both video and audio are very laggy. 
Although I have a relatively powerful pc. 
Details:
Intel i7-2670QM, 8GB of ram, Nvidia GT 540M 2GB - vc

On the virtual box I've given 8 cpu's and 5GB of ram. 
Enabled 3D acceleration and 128MB of video memory.

I have installed the guest additions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try changing from 8 cpu's to 1 cpu. Multiple CPU's only help in certain situations and in some cases can make things worse.

You shouldn't expect great performance, but you should be able to watch regular flash videos without a problem.

Comment: would then the vm be able to leverage the milti-core architecture ?

Comment: Yes, the VM would, but you aren't necessarily increasing performance due to the virtualization overhead.

Comment: Less is more. 8 CPUs is illogical on a 4 core processor. If you must have multiple processors in your VM, knock them back to two.

Comment: making the virtual CPU just one core helped :) I'll see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Flash player on linux has poor performance. Try using the Opera Browser whis is the best browser I tested on linux for playing flash (compared to Firefox, Chrome and Maxthon).